# Android Realm Upgrade guide?

Tags: android, realm

I'm currently using Realm 0.88.2 and looking to upgrade to the latest stable version. Is there an upgrade guide available listing gotchas and code changes to make?

I guess the changelog at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md is a start, but mayybe other resources are available as well..

Comment: Well there's this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project/39974275#39974275 just check 0.89.0 and above, personally I would recommend upgrading only to 1.1.1 at moment.

Comment: (as long as you don't open the Realm directly on external storage - If you do, stick to 0.88.3)

Comment: I flagged my own question as duplicate of the one @EpicPandaForce mentioned