# Realm PrimaryKey Constraint Exception

Tags: android, realm

i had a problem with realm i try to fill realm with my data i got it from json and after parse json and every thing is ready i use it but its crashed my app and this is my code

```
private void putDataInRealm(ArrayList<Movie> resultObj) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (Movie item : resultObj) {
        movieDb = realm.createObject(MovieDb.class);
        movieDb.setMovieID(item.getId());
        movieDb.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        movieDb.setDate(item.getDate());
        movieDb.setOverview(item.getOverview());
        movieDb.setRate(item.getRate());
        movieDb.setVote(item.getVote());
        movieDb.setBackdrop_path(item.getBackdrop());
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

sure i download realm and i make my configuration like that

```
 RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).name("Movie_data_base.realm").build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
```

my error is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.massive.movieapp, PID: 27784
              io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 
                  at io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException(Table.java:675)
                  at io.realm.internal.Table.addEmptyRow(Table.java:404)
                  at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:696)
                  at com.massive.movieapp.FragmentForActivity.putDataInRealm(FragmentForActivity.java:135)
                  at com.massive.movieapp.FragmentForActivity.onPostExcuteCallBack(FragmentForActivity.java:150)
                  at com.massive.movieapp.Url_cont.onPostExecute(Url_cont.java:128)
                  at com.massive.movieapp.Url_cont.onPostExecute(Url_cont.java:25)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my device is nexus 7 api 23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly what the error says. You're trying to put an object in the database, but it already has an object with the same value of the `@PrimaryKey`-annotated field. Primary key is by definition unique - it has to identify and reference exactly one object in the database.

A simple way to fix that case is to create the `MovieDB` as an **unmanaged** object, and then use `realm.insertOrUpdate` method (available from v1.1.0) which will check for existence of an object with the same key, and update it if exists or create a new one if it doesn't:

```
private void putDataInRealm(ArrayList<Movie> resultObj) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (Movie item : resultObj) {
        MovieDb movieDb = new MovieDb();
        movieDb.setMovieID(item.getId());
        movieDb.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        movieDb.setDate(item.getDate());
        movieDb.setOverview(item.getOverview());
        movieDb.setRate(item.getRate());
        movieDb.setVote(item.getVote());
        movieDb.setBackdrop_path(item.getBackdrop());
        realm.insertOrUpdate(movieDb);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: when i put  realm.insertOrUpdate(movieDb); android studio say cant resolve this method

Comment: What version of realm are you using? Is it the latest one? It has to be AT LEAST 1.1.0 The method IS there https://realm.io/docs/java/2.2.0/api/ Or maybe MovieDb is not extending RealmObject or RealmModel?

Comment: MovieDb is extending RealmObject and my realm is io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1

Comment: could you send for me latest version from realm

Comment: The latest version docs are available here  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/ although updating isn't so simple due to a bunch of breaking changes on the way. You should probably try to update to 0.88.3., which also uses the Gradle plugin solution rather than just `compile 'io.realm...`.

Comment: Its true there are major breaking changes throughout Realm releases, but from the look of the question it seems like this is some learning/experimental/early work so there's probably no important reason to not update and refactor. I'd strongly suggest starting off with the newest version (2.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

That's because you should specify the ID  on the creation of the RealmObject. (available since 0.90.0)

```
for (Movie item : resultObj) {
    movieDb = realm.createObject(MovieDb.class, item.getId());
    //movieDb.setMovieID(item.getId());
```

Or you could use unmanaged object and insert it (since 1.1.0)

```
for (Movie item : resultObj) {
    movieDb = new MovieDb();
    movieDb.setMovieID(item.getId());
   ... 
    realm.insertOrUpdate(movieDb);
```

But in older times, you would do the following

```
for (Movie item : resultObj) {
    movieDb = new MovieDb();
    movieDb.setMovieID(item.getId());
   ... 
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(movieDb);
```

Comment: your why dose not work it give error i cant any thing beside MovieDb.class

Comment: Then you should update your Realm version to at least 1.1.1 one day, because this functionality was added in 0.90.0. Which was 1.5 years ago.

Comment: Here is an upgrade guide  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project/39974275#39974275

Comment: please tell me how to put latest version of realm in my android studio i knew that stupid question but i need the answer

Comment: As mentioned by the [**official documentation**](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/), you need to add this to the project level build gradle: `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"` and add this to the module level build gradle: `apply plugin: 'realm-android'`

Comment: It does, you just need to handle the breaking changes.