# java.lang.Double is not supported Realm Object

Tags: java, android, firebase, realm

Basically I had a working app using realm that would work fine until I tried to import firebase into it and things changed. It wouldnt see realm anymore and after I fixed relam import, now it says

```
Error:(10, 8) error: Type java.lang.Double of field price is not supported
```

this is how my class looks like:

```
public class RealmTruck extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String name;

    private String location;
    private Double price;
    private Integer registrationYear;
    private String version;
```

I mention again that this was working. And if I switch realm from 0.82.1 version to 0.83.0.+ I get this:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches io.realm:realm-android:0.83.0.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         0.87.5
         0.87.4
         0.87.3
         0.87.2
         0.87.1
         + 31 more
     Required by:
         LoginTest:app:unspecified
```

What is going on? I really didnt change anything to it. I tried recompiling, reimporting, clearing cached indexes, nothing works.

If I try grandle sync now, I get this:

```
Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: io.realm:realm-android:0.83.0.+
<a href="openFile:D:/Projects2016/Android/LoginTest/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I'm using Android Studio, the latest version I believe

Comment: have you tried specifying an explicit version rather than a version range?

Comment: Ok, that worked. I dont understand why because before it worked with the range but removing the .+ made my app work again. Thank you

Comment: This syntax isn't super-well documented but I think your range describes a four part version and the library just has a standard three part semver version. So it is not found.

Comment: Switching to `0.83.0` is a bad idea :( you should switch at least to 0.87.5, at least anything higher than 0.87.2 (inclusive), but lower than 0.89.0 (exclusive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Realm doesn't support `Double`, `Integer`, etc. classes before 0.83.0.

0.83.0 and above introduced `NULL support`, which allows nullable primitives.

Although it's [recommended that you upgrade at least to 0.87.5 or 0.88.3 without changing too much existing logic in your Realm code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39974275/2413303).

If this is a new project, and Realm is newly introduced, then you should go for either [1.2.0](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f), or the latest version available.