# using Realm in Android project with armeabi support only

Tags: android, android-ndk, realm

I'm trying to use Realm. I setup the build.gradle and called Realm.init(context) on app start.

The problem is, the app crashes on launch.

Here's the log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.test.android com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5406)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                      Caused by: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so
                                                                         at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ApkLibraryInstaller.installLibrary(ApkLibraryInstaller.java:85)
                                                                         at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibraryInternal(ReLinkerInstance.java:180)
                                                                         at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibrary(ReLinkerInstance.java:136)
                                                                         at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:70)
                                                                         at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:57)
                                                                         at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:59)
                                                                         at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:187)
```

The project uses another library that only supports `armeabi`. that's why I added an abiFilter

`ndk { abiFilters "armeabi" }`

Adding other values in here will cause that library to crash.

Is there a way for me to use Realm for "armeabi" only?

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the same issue.Just now solved it by adding this realm version to project level gradle        `classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.0'`

[link here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200)

Answer (score 5):

Solved.

just to updated gradle classpath to classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.11.0"

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.11.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files`enter code here`


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that since Realm 2.0, `armeabi` support was removed, and only `armeabi-v7` works (read [change log: `armeabi is not supported anymore`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200)).

There is an issue [tracking it here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3506).

However, you can still use Realm 1.2.0, which works just as well. You can refer to [this guide for the breaking changes in 2.x so that you can revert that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project/39974275#39974275), otherwise it works exactly the same.