# It is safe to upgrade realm-gradle-plugin version?

Tags: android, realm, upgrade, realm-java

I upgraded it from `1.0.0` to `3.3.2` on debug version and everything seems to work, but I wonder if there are any breaking changes that may lead to release application crash or worse to existing schema corruption?
Are there any promises/guarantees/warnings about library upgrades?

Comment: Well there is a change log https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md so it depends?

Comment: Technically your safest upgrade bet (for your version) is `1.2.0`

Comment: But you can actually also see a list of breaking changes between versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project/39974275#39974275)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank for your answers! Last link is **very** useful, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

-Its recommended to upgrade to last version and have not problem just need to change some syntax which deprecated .

- Last version is `5.1.0`

for more look in : [upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project/39974275)