# Gradle plugin version conflicting with realm gradle version Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, realm

When I am using "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2" with "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0" it is working fine, but I want to use realm version 1.2.0. Now it is conflicting and giving error like:

> Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
>
> Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

[image]

[image]

I already made changes with Implementation and AnnotationProcessor in app level gradle file. How can I use realm 1.2.0 version with latest android tools gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Realm 1.2.0 won't work anymore with AS 3.0+.  It was Realm 2.2.0 that added support for `annotationProcessor` configuration, which is now mandatory to use. But Realm 5.1.0 is out there, so if this is a new project, there is no reason to use Realm 1.2.0 instead of 5.1.0

Comment: its an old project, and a lots of code done with 1.2.0. If I use 2.2.0, will it work for minimal code change?

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project if i remember correctly the last of the Realm 2.x series was 2.3.2 -- but the changes between 1.x and 2.x are fairly minimal compared to the changes between 2.x and 3.x which changes RealmResults iteration behavior in transactions (again)

Comment: Realm 1.2.0 is working fine with 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3 and Android Studio 3.0.1. Can I use any gradle hack(like: exclude/resolutionStrategy)?