# Upgrading Realm databases created in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, realm

I have been using Realm for a while now in a WPF app using Costura.
https://blog.jonstodle.com/using-realm-with-fody-costura/

Everything is working fine, but when I try to open a database file created in .NET, I am presented with this message. I've updated all my nuget packages, as well as the realm-wrapper files in the costura directories. It occurs with old, existing databases as well as newly created ones.

Is there some sort of migration I can perform to update existing databases as well as create databases in this new format from now on?

[image: Message on opening the database file in Realm Studio]

Comment: Have you seen this: [Upgrade realm in an Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971209/upgrade-realm-in-an-android-project)

Comment: yes. it's for android.i don't see anything in there that relates

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, when it comes to realm there are two things you can do:

1. Delete the old db file and create a new one
2. Use migrations. Migration in realm is seperated into two different parts

   - Schema versioning automatic migration
   - Schema versioning custom migration

There is alot to cover about these two subjects and it will be too long for this post.
You will havae a better time reading it at [realm swift guide part 6](https://medium.com/@aliakhtar_16369/migration-with-realm-realmswift-part-6-11c3a7b24955).