# Realm Inconsistent results

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, rx-android

In my project i am using clean architecture. The following code below is in my domain and data layers. Its an generic implementation so i don't have to repeat it for every model. This code works fine, i have tested it a million times. But after releasing my app, some phones (Huawei p8) are experiencing weird behavior from the database. Once i would call getList(X) from a certain activity the results are fine then i go to another activity make the same call but the response is empty. Sometimes i would receive an extra item that it is just full of nulls and default values. I am using the realm plugin 1.2. I really need to fix this bug. I would appreciate any sort of help.

```
@Override
public Observable getList(@NonNull GetRequest genericUseCaseRequest) {
    return mRepository.getListDynamically(genericUseCaseRequest.getUrl(), genericUseCaseRequest
            .getPresentationClass(), genericUseCaseRequest.getDataClass(), genericUseCaseRequest
            .isPersist(), genericUseCaseRequest.isShouldCache()).compose(applySchedulers());
}
```

---

```
@Override
public Observable<List> getListDynamically(@NonNull String url, Class presentationClass, @NonNull Class dataClass,
                                           boolean persist, boolean shouldCache) {
    try {
        return mDataStoreFactory.dynamically(url, true, mEntityMapperUtil.getDataMapper(dataClass))
                .dynamicGetList(url, presentationClass, dataClass, persist, shouldCache);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Observable.error(e);
    }
}
```

---

```
public DataStore dynamically(@NonNull String url, boolean isGet, EntityMapper entityDataMapper) throws IllegalAccessException {
    if (!url.isEmpty() && (!isGet || Utils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)))
        return new CloudDataStore(new RestApiImpl(), mDataBaseManager, entityDataMapper);
    else if (mDataBaseManager == null)
        throw new IllegalAccessException(getInstance().getContext().getString(R.string.no_db));
    else
        return new DiskDataStore(mDataBaseManager, entityDataMapper);
```

### }

```
@Override
public Observable<List> getAll(Class clazz) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(clazz).findAll()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer applies if you use `Schedulers.io()`**:

Have you considered closing your Realm instance that you open on your thread pool?

Because if you don't close the Realm (which you don't), then you'll experience [version retention](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/understanding-realm-version-retention-and-synchronization-9a513c2445bb#.o94he8kh2) and your Realm instance in your background thread will never get updated again.

Also consider refreshing the Realm after opening the instance using [this force-refresh workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839808/2413303).

But also make sure you close the instance.  In fact, considering you're trying to use a background thread for your query, you should consider using `realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults)` so that you can close the instance freely.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but
IllegalArgumentException: RealmObject is not valid, so it cannot be copied.  Observable.defer(() -> { Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            List finalResult = null;
            try {
                finalResult = Collections.singletonList(clazz.newInstance());
                finalResult = realm.copyFromRealm(finalResult);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
            realm.close();
            return Observable.just(finalResult); })