# Cannot set up Realm in project using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, realm, kotlin

I'm trying to build a test project in Kotlin with Realm. 
Here's my model:

```
open class Book : RealmObject() {

    // Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
    @PrimaryKey
    open var id: Long = 0

    open var title = ""

    open var description = ""

    open var author = ""

    open var imageUrl = ""
}
```

and here's exception I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: app.androidhive.info.realm, PID: 18782
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.androidhive.info.realm/app.androidhive.info.realm.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Book is not part of the schema for this Realm
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Book is not part of the schema for this Realm
```

I searched around for the solution so and added  `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.2"` in build.gradle and 
`apply plugin: 'realm-android'` and

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // Realm
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'
    kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations:0.87.4"
    kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:0.87.4"
}
```

into build script in module app. It gives me another problem:

```
Error:(15, 48) Cannot access '<init>': it is public/*package*/ in 

'Builder'
/Volumes/Toshiba/Users/macuser/Development/Android/Exersises/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/realmtest/realm/RealmController.kt
Error:(27, 15) Unresolved reference: refresh
Error:(34, 15) Unresolved reference: clear
Error:(53, 23) Unresolved reference: allObjects

[KOTLIN] deleting /Volumes/Toshiba/Users/macuser/Development/Android/Exersises/MyApplication/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
```

I can only build my project successfully if Book is written in java. 
Any suggestion how to make Realm and Kotlin work together?

Comment: You shouldn't add version 0.87.4 along with version 2.2.3

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, do you mean verson 2.2.3 of io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin? I've tried this and I've got "Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.3" gradle build Error

Answer (score 2):

Use RealmClass annotation + RealmModel interface

```
import io.realm.Realm
import io.realm.RealmModel
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey
import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass

@RealmClass
open class Example(
    @PrimaryKey open var Id : Long = 0,
    open var Field : String = ""
) : RealmModel
```

In module gradle file add

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

In project gradle file add

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.2"
```

No additional compile/kapt needed

Comment: Thanks, @Эльнар Берхеев, it helped! Just in case it would help someone: I had to make few other changes to build the project.

Comment: Theres no need for args in RealmConfiguretion.Build() call and I had to call Realm.init(context) before it. Also refresh(), clean() and allObjects() method were replaced with waitForChange(), delete() and where().findAll() methods respectively, as stated here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2864. Cheers!

Comment: waitForChange()  works differently than refresh(), use this instead  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38839808/2413303

Answer (score 2):

Realm java 4.1.0 has been released and most problem of Realm with Kotlin has resolved! You don't need to use `open var` just use `var`. You can test [my sample project](https://github.com/c2c2/RealmKotlinShop). My sample is for testing module in Realm object Server with kotlin.