# Realm returning stale data

Tags: java, android, database, realm, kotlin

I don't have a lot of experience writing Android apps. For fun I am writing an app that will upload my call logs to my server. This entire app is running as a Service. The Service (starts when the phone is booted) is the one that registers the ContentObserver, which then calls my custom `CallLog` class. I use `ContentObserver` to listen for content change events. Unfortunately, the ContentObserver is called multiple times when I e.g. dial a number.

For that reason, I have function that I call after a successful upload (I use Retrofit) called `markAsUploaded()`. This function creates a `RealmObject` called `CallLogUploaded` (which is different from my regular `CallLog` model). This `CallLogUploaded` simply has one identifier which is the `dateTime` of the call, which should be unique enough. Then, when I am iterating through the list of all the call logs, I check every single call log against a `isDataUploaded()` function, which does a Realm query and checks to see if there is already a call log with that dateTime stored in the database (realm). In theory, it should work.

However, I have noticed that it does not always work. It seems that very often my data is stale. When I do `realm.isAutoRefresh()`, it returns false (although I swear it returned true once). In my `isDataUploaded` function, even when I do a `findAll()` on the Realm, I do not see all of my data - but the data definitely did hit the `markDataAsUploaded` function.

Here's my code - it's in Kotlin but should be easy to understand:

```
    val callLogCall = service.sendCalLLogs(childId, dataToUpload)
    callLogCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.i(AppConstants.LOG_TAG, "Call log data uploaded successfully!")
                this@CallLogData.markDataAsUploaded(dataToUpload)
            } else {
                Log.w(AppConstants.LOG_TAG, "Call log data upload failed")
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.w(AppConstants.LOG_TAG, "Call log data upload error (onFailure) called")
        }
    })


// This function simply stores a Realm model for all the data that has been uploaded to the server
private fun markDataAsUploaded(dataToUpload: List<CallLog>) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    for (data in dataToUpload) {
        realm.beginTransaction()
        val callLogUploaded = realm.createObject(CallLogUploaded::class.java)
        callLogUploaded.callDate = data.callDate

        realm.commitTransaction()
    }
}

// This function checks to see if the data is already uploaded.
private fun isDataUploaded(callLog: CallLog) : Boolean { 
    return realm
            .where(CallLogUploaded::class.java)
            .equalTo("callDate", callLog.callDate)
            .count() > 0L
}

// Gets the call logs - not the entire function
for (call in callLogs) {
    val callLog = CallLog()
    callLog.id = call.id
    callLog.callDate = Utilities.getTimestampAsSeconds(call.callDate)

    if (this.isDataUploaded(callLog)) {
        continue
    }

    callLog.name = call.name
    callLog.number = call.number
 }
```

I am very new to Realm and fairly new to Android development, so I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
// This function simply stores a Realm model for all the data that has been uploaded to the server
private fun markDataAsUploaded(dataToUpload: List<CallLog>) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    for (data in dataToUpload) {
        realm.beginTransaction()
        val callLogUploaded = realm.createObject(CallLogUploaded::class.java)
        callLogUploaded.callDate = data.callDate

        realm.commitTransaction()
    }
}
```

This method has [quite a few errors that I had written about a long time ago](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149)

- The Realm instance is opened, but never closed
- There is a new transaction per every element, rather than inserting all elements in a single transaction

If you don't close the Realm instance (each instance requires its own `close()` call), then your Realm instance will never update unless you actually begin a transaction and do things inside the transaction.

You have three solutions:

1.) do your logic on the background thread inside a transaction, if there is nothing to be done, then cancel the transaction - queries made in transactions are never stale

2.) make sure the Realm instance is closed properly (although this is definitely a necessity on any non-autoupdating thread)

3.) a hacky solution is to call [`RealmRefresh.refreshRealm()` after `getDefaultInstance()` according to my answer on Stack Overflow which relies on package-private API, but it works to solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839808/2413303)

---

Typically you need to open the Realm instance at the beginning of the thread, and close it at the end of the thread.

so, it's basically one big `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance() { ... }` for `onHandleIntent()`.

---

`enqueue(new Callback() { @Override public void onSuccess(..) {...}` runs on the UI thread. To run it on the current thread, you should use `call.execute()`.

---

instead of

```
for (data in dataToUpload) {
    realm.beginTransaction()
    val callLogUploaded = realm.createObject(CallLogUploaded::class.java)
    callLogUploaded.callDate = data.callDate

    realm.commitTransaction()
}
```

do

```
realm.beginTransaction()
for (data in dataToUpload) {
    val callLogUploaded = realm.createObject(CallLogUploaded::class.java)
    callLogUploaded.callDate = data.callDate
}
realm.commitTransaction()
```

---

In order to understand about version retention you can read https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/understanding-realm-version-retention-and-synchronization-9a513c2445bb .